How many listeners running parallelly while using @SqsListener in spring boot application
I have a spring-boot based application and I am using AWS SQS fifo queue. To poll the messages from the queue, I have used aws spring cloud SqsListener.
I have a use case with FIFO SQS queue having 1000 message in queue in which some of the message have same messageGroupId and some of them have different messageGroupId.So in this case I have observed that SqsListener always polling 10 messages from the queue and starting the processing of this messages in following below order based on the messageGroupId .
1.If messageGroupId is same for all 10 message- Then it starts the processing of messages in sequence one by one.
2.If messageGroupId is unique for all 10 message-Then it starts the processing of this messages parallelly.
3.If messageGroupId is Jumbled (Ex: If first 3 Message have same messageGroupId and other 7 have different and unique messageGroupId)- Then it start the processing 8 messages like 1 message out of 3 messages which have same messageGroupId and remaining 7 which have unique messageGroupId. after processing these 8 messages it start processing 2 remaining messages one by one which have same messageGroupId. After completion of these messages it poll next messages from the queue.
I have the My SqsListener code something like this.
`
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue.oa}", factory = "acknowledgementModeFactory")

    public void receiveMessage(String event, Message message,Acknowledgement acknowledgment) throws IOException, 
        InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  
    log.info("Event received by event processor as : ");
    try{
       // logic
    }catch(Exception e){
        
    }finally {
        acknowledgment.acknowledgeAsync().get();
    }
}`

From the above peace of code I am getting the below log message
2024-09-13T13:31:25.654+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[nc-response-1-7\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractSqsMessageSource     : Received 10 messages \[7c877df5-0729-4f46-a8aa-7011b640a772, 9e034e1a-4210-4324-b679-e3ea0064fc65, f621b181-787b-4937-b9fd-f0c2d5364c43, 0de74824-69ba-42bb-b7f9-093dfaca613e, 4279d7c1-76d6-464b-bbb3-ba13c2095647, f03dcd94-e9ac-48bb-b503-20b5cfe9a40f, 4ecdf2be-60a6-4a94-80b5-01f25f2b456a, 84c5b213-1ce2-478b-9ced-2441166dbf40, 8e749838-91e4-4eb1-9bb5-3f29d3e3e547, d7727e27-3ad2-4d74-a608-bd511967b6b2\] from queue https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/618429669340/test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:25.654+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[nc-response-1-7\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Released 0 unused permits for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:25.655+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-1\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.655+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-2\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.655+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-6\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-4\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[tContainer#1-10\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-7\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-8\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-9\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-3\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.656+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-5\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:25.965+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-5\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:25.980+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-4\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:25.993+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-2\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.003+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[tContainer#1-10\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.003+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-3\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.018+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-8\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.018+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-6\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.018+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-9\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.025+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-1\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.026+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-7\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.026+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[essage_source-1\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : 10 permits acquired for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.026+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[essage_source-1\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractSqsMessageSource     : Polling queue https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/618429669340/test.fifo for 10 messages.
2024-09-13T13:31:26.028+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[essage_source-1\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Requesting permits for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.668+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[nc-response-1-4\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractSqsMessageSource     : Received 10 messages \[cffea23c-4bd1-4ec4-9cdd-8a87c7e3f05b, f88c4c70-c92b-4618-9884-ba0af0e5e0dc, c5456b2f-0945-48b4-b200-52918acc9ffc, 9fcee032-e7c4-4344-bf23-105177a698ba, 61ed04c0-954d-4e71-bd37-56e03ad3ed51, 29dc959b-a343-491d-9160-b1cc07562189, f9971094-c17c-488c-aff5-ed8a02a477b7, 2f7a7c53-1302-4e1c-bc7d-551a60b06eb7, fde1eca3-8180-4063-963a-73a6a5930c88, 9f44281b-f3a3-45d4-b1ad-106d4b8f1b9b\] from queue https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/618429669340/test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.668+05:30 TRACE 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[nc-response-1-4\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Released 0 unused permits for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.668+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-5\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.668+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-4\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.668+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-2\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[tContainer#1-19\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-8\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-1\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-7\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-3\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-9\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.669+05:30  INFO 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-6\] c.i.p.n.u.p.sqs.consumer.OASqsConsumer   : Event received by event processor as :
2024-09-13T13:31:26.961+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-4\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.980+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- [uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-3\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.989+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[ntContainer#1-7\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo
2024-09-13T13:31:26.990+05:30 DEBUG 14064 --- \[uapi-event-processor\] \[tContainer#1-19\] i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource : Releasing permit for queue test.fifo

**In the above log messages we are getting this notations like [tContainer#1-19] and  [ntContainer#1-7] so this numbers range #1-1 , #1-2 .#1-19 these numbers are increasing this way as shown in the log messages
Here my questions is
Q1:what is these notations?
for Ex:#1-1 and #1-2 and so on . What does it mean?
Q2:If these are the Thread notations then how many threads it is creating in the system. if it is creating in this way like 1-19 and similarly it increases more and more can it impact our CPU utilization in Production scenario?
